# Paypal email notification on sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hey I was working with Paypal express checkout and I wondering if the notifications that I receive after someone has made a payment is according to the DoExpressCheckout response? and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the PayPal payment notification sent as a result of your DoExpressCheckout call. You can, however, send them an email yourself in addition to it.

Comment: Is there any way I can have more informations sent to me after a payment has been made to me in the email?

Comment: Actually, you can use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/) to have data sent to your server directly that contains all pertinent payment info

Comment: I am looking to modify the info sent to me by PayPal only for the email notification, not the IPN.